# Swagger-UI like API documentation tool for API written in Golang and consumes/produces protocolBuffer input/output

Tags: api, go, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-go

I am developing a web product with Rest APIs which is using protocol buffers in Golang.
In my earlier products, we used Swagger for automated API documentation as they were using JSON for request/response. We are aiming at the same functionality/tool for integration but haven't found an ideal match.
Is there any tool that we should consider or look into?

Comment: https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcui

Comment: @vearutop its for grpc server...ours are rest APIs using protocol buffer